# The annotation 'id' conflicts with a field on the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

In Annotate I am trying to get the count of quires for which `is_healthy` is `True` but I am getting an Error `The annotation 'id' conflicts with a field on the model.`
Any solution to solve this? and why is this causing how can i resolve this?

```
DeviceHealthHistory.objects.filter(**filter_data).values(
  id = F('id'),
).annotate(
   healthy_count=Count('id', filter=Q(is_healthy=True)),
)
```

Comment: Please describe sample dataset and expected result. It's unclear what exactly you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for count then you use `count` function fo queryset:

```
DeviceHealthHistory.objects.filter(**filter_data).filter(is_healthy=True).count()
```

To get other fields along with the count.

```
DeviceHealthHistory.objects.filter(**filter_data).values(
  'other_field1'
).annotate(
   healthy_count=Count('id', filter=Q(is_healthy=True)),
)
```

Comment: I need count of healthy_devices as one of the value along with some other data. That's why I have done the annotate. your query will give me just count of records.

Comment: You dont need `=F('id')`. You can use the field name directly. Note that counting id with the id in the result set itself will not give you correct results. I am assuming you will have a different set of fields in `values`

Answer (score 0):

You should count with:

```
DeviceHealthHistory.objects.filter(**filter_data, is_healthy=True).count()
```

This will filter on the `**filter_data` and also ensure that it only counts records with `is_healthy=True`. We then count the number of records.

If you want to "group by" a certain field, like `patient_id`, you can work with:

```
DeviceHealthHistory.objects.filter(**filter_data).values('patient_id').annotate(
    n=Count('pk', filter=Q(is_healthy=True))
).order_by('patient_id')
```

This will produce a queryset of *dictionaries* with `'patient_id'` and `'n'` as keys, and the patient and the corresponding counts as values.